# Convert bytes to int and back java/python

Tags: java, python, int, byte

I am converting an arbitrary ascii string, which is incidently a number padded with zeros, for example "1" as "0000000001" then to bytes then back in python. Of course the value can be "0000004231" etc. also. It is always numeric and within range of signed 32bit value padded by zeros.

When I tell python that it is bytes and I want it in int, it converts it to a nice large random looking number. Then I can convert it back to original value later using `to_bytes()` function.

```
In [74]: value = int.from_bytes(bytes(format(1, '010d'),'ascii'), byteorder='little')                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [75]: value.to_bytes(10,byteorder=sys.byteorder)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[75]: b'0000000001'

In [76]: value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[76]: 232284873704446901628976

In [77]:
```

How can I achieve same with java?

Comment: Can you specify what the difference is between `value` in the first line (contents="ascii"?) and in the second line (where contents is mostly ASCII '0')? Can you specify what relevance the number has? The number is the decimal representation of only the first eight ASCII '0's and discards the trailing two.

Comment: I need the number to be padded with zeros and 10 characters long. It is a number in range of 32bit signed int with padding to fixed 10 character length

Comment: 'nice large random looking number' triggers my alarms. To you it may look random, but in hexadecimal (to the computer) it looks like 0x3030303030303030. (0x30 is ASCII for 'number zero') Did you even see that 0000000001 has the same number as 0000000099? What is the purpose of this number? This sounds like a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: what do you mean by 0000000001 is same as 0000000099. 1 => 232284873704446901628976 and 99 => 270229826264067449303088
Not same? The purpose is to make a fixed length number another fixed length longer number which you can't recognize at first glance. But nevermind...

Comment: Ah my mistake. The calculator has large integer support but apparently limits hexadecimals to 64 bits. To get a 'random looking number' for any string, just use `string.hashCode()`.

Comment: I already gave up on this idea. But the point was that I get same values on Java and Python. Also I need to be able to reverse it, eg. 270229826264067449303088 => 99. So I can create the longer value in Python, and read with Java and figure out it was 99. As I understand in Java `hashCode()` returns a memory address so it is different every time a program is run... But anyway, I gave up on this as I mentioned. It does not seem to be worth the trouble :)

Comment: Hashcode doesn't return a memory address, it's designed to be the same every run. Anyway, see my answer for a Python-Java compatible solution

Comment: Yes, I was looking at Object `hashCode()` which changes, but String `hashCode()` seems fixed. But it does not seem to be possible to convert it back to original value. Anyway, like I said I have given up on this idea :) But thanks for your effort. I select your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exact(?) functional replica of your code in Java:

```
String string = String.format("%010d", 1); // I hope this format is correct

byte[] bigEndian    = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bigEndian)); // [48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49]

byte[] littleEndian = new byte[bigEndian.length];
for (int i = 0; i < bigEndian.length; i++)
    littleEndian[littleEndian.length - i - 1] = bigEndian[i];

BigInteger value = new BigInteger(littleEndian);
System.out.println(value); // 232284873704446901628976
```

And back:

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("232284873704446901628976");

byte[] littleEndian = value.toByteArray();

byte[] bigEndian = new byte[littleEndian.length];
for (int i = 0; i < littleEndian.length; i++)
    bigEndian[bigEndian.length - i - 1] = littleEndian[i];

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bigEndian)); // [48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49]

String string = new String(bigEndian, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.println(string); // 0000000001

int number = Integer.parseInt(string);
System.out.println(number); // 1
```

In any case, if you make the python code use big-endian, you can skip the array reversals in Java.

Comment: This seems to do exactly same. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm no good with Python, but perhaps something like this:

```
String test = "0000000001";
byte[] testBytes = test.getBytes(); // If needed pass an encoding as argument
String newTest = new String(testBytes); // Again, if needed, pass an encoding as argument
```

Comment: I already tried this. I get `[B@7852e922` in the `testBytes` variable and not `232284873704446901628976` which I expect ?